# Invalid Identifier. Is it the concat code?

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting an error "invalid identifier" and I know the columns are right...  any thoughts?

Also, I know the concat coding is kind of messy. Someone offered this code for it:

```
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME as TEEN
```

which would be better?

```
SELECT
   mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE AS Category_id 
   ,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE AS SUBCATEGORY
   ,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
   ,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME 
   ,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME AS Color_Name 
   ,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY AS PSLD 
   ,CONCAT(mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME, CONCAT(',', CONCAT(' ',mp_asin.COLOR_NAME))) AS Teen 
   ,mp.BRAND_CODE AS Brand_Code 
   ,mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE as REPLEN_CODE 
   ,mp.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID AS Replen_TIER
   ,mp.ASIN as ASIN
   , MIN(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (CONCAT(mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME, CONCAT(',', CONCAT(' ',mp_asin.COLOR_NAME))))) as MIN_TEEN_RC
   , MAX(mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY (CONCAT(mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME, CONCAT(',', CONCAT(' ',mp_asin.COLOR_NAME))))) as MAX_TEEN_RC

FROM
D_MP_ASINS mp

WHERE
MIN_TEEN_RC <> MAX_TEEN_RC
AND mp.PRODUCT_CATEGORY =('30905500') 
AND mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE =('30905560')
AND mp.REGION_ID = 1
AND mp.MARKETPLACE_ID = 1
AND mp.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = 309

Group by
mp_asin.CATEGORY_CODE
,mp_asin.SUBCATEGORY_CODE 
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN
,mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME
,mp_asin.COLOR_NAME
,mp_asin.PRODUCT_SITE_LAUNCH_DAY
,CONCAT(mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME, CONCAT(',', CONCAT(' ',mp_asin.COLOR_NAME)))
,mp.BRAND_CODE
,mp.REPLENISHMENT_CODE
,mp.REPLENISHMENT_CATEGORY_ID
,mp.ASIN
```

Comment: Did you check for typos? Also, what is the complete error message?

Comment: Here is the error code:

Comment: Statement 1 is not valid. ORA-00904: "MP_ASIN"."COLOR_NAME": invalid identifier

Comment: And said column does exist in said table?

Comment: All of the columns in select exist in the table.  I opened the table to copy the column name exactly.  Thanks for the suggestion on the concat code.  I thought maybe that was the problem.  Is there an error due to the # of characters there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the table which alias **mp_asin**. I see only one table in `FROM` clause.

This is better and more readable:

`mp_asin.PARENT_ASIN_NAME || ', ' || mp_asin.COLOR_NAME as TEEN`